# Plain Tex and Tikz: pgfsys-dvi.def does not support color

Tags: tikz-pgf, plain-tex

Here it is my little example

```
\magnification 1200
\def\pagetop{792}

\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\input tikz.tex
\usepgflibrary{arrows}

\tikzpicture
   \draw[color=red,line width=2pt] plot (0,0) -- (2.5,1.0) -- (4.0,2.0) -- (7.5,5.0) --    (10.0,10.0);
\endtikzpicture
\bye
```

Here it is the log it get

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=etex 2020.10.11)  7 NOV 2020 05:39
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**2020_11_05_oepq.tex
(./2020_11_05_oepq.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks13
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen16
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen17

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.t
ex)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-plain.def
\pgfutil@tempcnta=\count27
\pgfutil@tempcntb=\count28
\pgfutil@tempboxa=\box16
\pgfutil@flushglue=\skip18
\pgfutil@abb=\box17
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/atbegshi/atbegshi.sty
Package: atbegshi 2019/12/05 v1.19 At begin shipout hook (HO)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\AtBeginShipoutBox=\box18

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Loading package pgfrcs version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
))
Loading package pgf version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Loading package pgfsys version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks14
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks15

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.t
ex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks16
))
\pgf@x=\dimen18
\pgf@y=\dimen19
\pgf@xa=\dimen20
\pgf@ya=\dimen21
\pgf@xb=\dimen22
\pgf@yb=\dimen23
\pgf@xc=\dimen24
\pgf@yc=\dimen25
\pgf@xd=\dimen26
\pgf@yd=\dimen27
\w@pgf@writea=\write0
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count29
\c@pgf@countb=\count30
\c@pgf@countc=\count31
\c@pgf@countd=\count32
\t@pgf@toka=\toks17
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks18
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks19
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count33
 (./pgf.cfg
Loading file pgf.cfg version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-dvi.def

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-dvi.def
Loading file pgfsys-dvi.def version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
\pgf@sys@dvi@path=\toks20
\pgf@sys@dvi@linewidth=\dimen28
\pgf@sys@dvi@pt@x=\dimen29
\pgf@sys@dvi@pt@y=\dimen30
)
(./2020_11_05_oepq.pgf)
\pgfutil@auxout=\write1
\openout1 = `2020_11_05_oepq.pgf'.

)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.
tex
Loading file pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count34
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count35
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.
tex
Loading file pgfsysprotocol.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Loading package pgfcore version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen31
\pgfmath@count=\count36
\pgfmath@box=\box19
\pgfmath@toks=\toks21
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks22
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks23
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonomet
ric.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.cod
e.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison
.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code
.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.
tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerari
thmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count37
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.te
x
Loading file pgfcorepoints.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
\pgf@picminx=\dimen32
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen33
\pgf@picminy=\dimen34
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen35
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen36
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen37
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen38
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen39
\pgf@xx=\dimen40
\pgf@xy=\dimen41
\pgf@yx=\dimen42
\pgf@yy=\dimen43
\pgf@zx=\dimen44
\pgf@zy=\dimen45
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.
code.tex
Loading file pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).

\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen46
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen47
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code
.tex
Loading file pgfcorepathusage.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen48
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen49
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.te
x
Loading file pgfcorescopes.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
\pgfpic=\box20
\pgf@hbox=\box21
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box22
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count38
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.c
ode.tex
Loading file pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
\pgflinewidth=\dimen50
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformation
s.code.tex
Loading file pgfcoretransformations.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b
).
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen51
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen52
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen53
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
Loading file pgfcorequick.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.t
ex
Loading file pgfcoreobjects.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing
.code.tex
Loading file pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b)
.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.te
x
Loading file pgfcorearrows.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen54
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
Loading file pgfcoreshade.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
\pgf@max=\dimen55
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count39
\pgf@shadingcount=\count40
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
Loading file pgfcoreimage.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.
tex
Loading file pgfcoreexternal.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box23
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.te
x
Loading file pgfcorelayers.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.c
ode.tex
Loading file pgfcoretransparency.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.
tex
Loading file pgfcorepatterns.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
Loading file pgfcorerdf.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex
Loading file pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box24
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
Loading file pgfmoduleplot.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/utilities/pgffor.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/plain/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Loading package pgffor version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen56
\pgffor@skip=\dimen57
\pgffor@stack=\toks24
\pgffor@toks=\toks25
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Loading package tikz version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers
.code.tex
Loading file pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b
).
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count41
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen58
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen59
\tikz@lasty=\dimen60
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen61
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen62
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen63
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen64
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen65
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen66
\tikz@figbox=\box25
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box26
\tikz@tempbox=\box27
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box28
\tikztreelevel=\count42
\tikznumberofchildren=\count43
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count44
\tikz@fig@count=\count45

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
Loading file pgfmodulematrix.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count46
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count47
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count48
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count49

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tik
zlibrarytopaths.code.tex
Loading file tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryarrows.code.
tex
Loading file pgflibraryarrows.code.tex version 2020/01/08 v3.1.5b (3.1.5b).
\arrowsize=\dimen67
)
Package pgf: Warning! Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvi.def does not support color
. This warning is given only once.
Package pgf: Warning! Your graphic driver pgfsys-dvi.def does not support path 
usage. This warning is given only once.
[1] )
Output written on 2020_11_05_oepq.dvi (1 page, 186844 bytes).
```

I get the above warning (whether I specify a colour or not).

Comment: By running `pdftex -output-format=dvi <tex-file>`, I cannot get the same warning. Which version of `pgf` are you using?

Comment: please show the complete log you get from that test file, in a code block so line endings are preserved. I get a different error with tex, but no error with etex,pdftex,xetex or luatex from your example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle done, editing the original post. I get the same warning using both etex and pdftex

Comment: Try by removing `pgf.cfg` in the current directory.

Comment: as Akira said (that's why a full log is always useful!)

Comment: @AkiraKakuto works, thanks.